# How exactly did Obito escape from Itachi's Amaterasu?

Tags: naruto

Itachi attacked Obito with Amaterasu through Sasuke's eyes, when Sasuke saw Obito's Sharingan. As soon as Obito was engulfed by the flames, he went into the dark region of the room and got rid of the lethal flame. How did he do it? Did he achieve that with Kamui?

Comment: I think its not revealed yet! :S

Comment: Is it possible that the amaterasu never actually touched Obito, since he can move parts of his body into dark space? Maybe he only wanted to make Itachi believe that the amaterasu hit him?

Answer (score 9):

I've been thinking about this question, and I've found a theory, which would explain a few things:

I'm almost 100% sure that the Amaterasu had hit Obito, as in the anime we can hear the damage being received. As from that moment, we can't talk about the Transportation Technique, because the Amaterasu lasts until his target is completely gone.

So that would reach the 5 minute limit and Obito would have been dead, just as it would've been the same result in the fight with Konan: those paper bombs kept coming, and they would've reach the 5 minutes limit, IF, and here it comes my theory. Obito escaped with the same technique both times, the Izanagi.

Since he had a lot of Sharingan eyes in reserve, he could have easily replaced the eye he had just used, just as he did after fighting Konan. AND he could have implied this, by the lines (if I recall well), "Even Itachi didn't know everything about me". That he could use Izanagi, or that he has those Sharingan reserves (since Itachi never knew about the eyes collected by Tobi, or Tobi's expertise in using this rare and forbidden jutsu).

Comment: good theory though!!!!!! but i can think of another theory,for instance,he made zetsu's clone to mimic like him(Tobi) and made him interrogate with Sasuke during it's first face to face conversation.We know that Tobi is a cautious guy(recalling his fight against Minato) and he thinks twice before taking any step....... anyway good theory and good effort......unfortunately we dont have any concrete proof though

Comment: yeah,this one is interesting too,but I couldn't believe, that even Obito would be able to mimic his sharingan into a Zetsu, because Itachi's Amaterasu reacted with Obito's sharingan, that would mean,that Obito transplanted his eye to Zetsu,si I can't imagine someone being able to "replicate" a sharingan in a host body:-??...yet,is interesting...It's kinda we're thinking the same way:)...you would be my "naruto soul-mate"? xD

Comment: isn't shinra tensei able to deflect the amaterasu fire. don't rem if obito had rinnegan or not but if he did then he must have used that instead.

Comment: @Rinneg4n i beleive what i meant was that since Zetsu can transform anything by touching a person,he converted himself into Tobi,and then he apprached in front of Sasuke. Tobi needn't have to transplant any sharingan or anything on Tobi's eyes.Recall the fight between Kisame and Bee.Zetsu came and transformed his body completely just by touching Kisame.

Comment: @Rikudu Sennin I think you can accept my asnwer,if you eould like

Answer (score 1):

At that time, Obito/Tobi doesn't have Rinnegan. The Rinnegan was in Nagato's possession. At that time the only Sharingan that had evolved into the Rinnegan was that of Uchiha Madara. Obito's was just a Mangekyou Sharingan. Therefore it definitely was not Shinra Tensei.

A possible explanation to how he get rid of the Amaterasu is that he used Izanagi using one of the Sharingans he collected. But it can't be said for 100% as it was never revealed in manga nor anime.

Since the Amaterasu hit him on his whole bod, [image: Tobi hit by Amaterasu]

he surely didn't do the same thing he did when he fought Danzo's bodyguard Fuu and Torune (pulling off his arm that is). Therefore I can say for 95% that it was Izanagi.

Answer (score 1):

he used Kamui. the third databook brought up the question of how he survived and talked about his ability to slip through things

Comment: This looks like the real answer, but it'd be better if you could also [edit] and mention the full title of the databook and quote some references related to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think zetsu had anything to do with it. And personally, I don't think he used the izanagi either. I think he used the same thing he uses to make things pass through him to escape it. Yes, the Amaterasu flames don't burn out until their target it burnt to a crisp, but think about it. Fire is energy, no matter what  how it is formed, and chakra is basically energy as well. The rasengan is made of chakra(energy), and it passed right through him to. So to the flames, it would be like their target was already gone, so they burn out. That's just what I think about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason can be

> [the flames burn fairly slowly, sometimes allowing anyone struck by Amaterasu an opportunity to remove whatever clothing or body parts have been caught ablaze.](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amaterasu#Overview)

This gave time Obito to separate him from his clothes. And for the part **Amaterasu** burn anything caught by it to ash or destroyed. Dress he was wearing will be destroyed by **Amaterasu**.

Answer (score 0):

You guys seem to not know that Obito's power is using the Kamui which the right eye can only be used if he is touching them where as the left eye is for long distance which is why Kakashi can only do it at distances but anyway the flame was touching Obito meaning he can transport it to the other dimension so there u go maybe u should look up his power before discussing

Comment: Maybe you can provide references and answer this yourself rather than telling people to "look up his power before discussing" which isn't very constructive

Comment: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kamui